# How to response a binary data from sql query(like LONGBLOB type) on node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I wanna response a binary data to the client on node.js.
but write can send string or Buffer only.
How can I send a binary to the client.

```
dbconnect.selectBinary(conn,function(result)
{
   //result is a binary from sql query.
   response.write(result,"binary"); //I wanna write response a binary here
   response.end();
}
```

Comment: buffers are binary, so if result is a buffer it will work as long as your headers (not shown) are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my result object had a "logo" BLOB in the DB, I use this code to convert to NodeJS lingo:

```
result.logo = new Buffer( result.logo, 'binary' );
```

Or sometimes this code (which is useful to me sometimes...):

```
result.logo = new Buffer( result.logo, 'binary' ).toString('base64');
```

Also, watch out that the result is not an array (with one entry). My actual code is like this, coming directly back from a node-mysql call:

```
result[0].logo = new Buffer( result[0].logo, 'binary' ).toString('base64');
```